# DrawerLayout: Disable clicks on content when drawer is open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a DrawerLayout which contains a ListView and a FrameLayout, which contains a TabHost. If I click in a empty area of my DrawerLayout, the click gets passed down to the FrameLayout, often changing the state of my tabs. The tabs are hidden from view, so I don't want this to happen.

Is there any method to intercept touch events when the DrawerLayout is open so this does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

This disallows to pass the event to its parent layout. (Stops event propogation).

Comment: But when I have to add this line ? :(

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:clickable="true"` tag on your sliding pane layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawer fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_layout, null);
    view.setClickable(true); // your solution!
    return view;
}
```